# Блоки не встают "по сетке". Как решить?

Tags: css, html

Хочу разместить блоке "по сетке". 3 блока в одной строчке.
Но если название у одного блока длинное, то вся сетка рушится.
Подскажите, как поправить?

https://jsfiddle.net/252jh1u8/

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #434343;
 }
 .wrapper {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
 }
 .item {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 29.666%;
  margin-right: 5.5%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  float: left;
 }
 .item:nth-child(3n) {
  margin-right: 0;
 }
 .item_img {
  height: 190px;
  background: #000;
 }
 .item_txt {
  padding: 10px
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">
   <div class="item_img"></div>
   <div class="item_txt">Какое-то длинное название блока, которое рушит всю можульность остальных блоков</div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
   <div class="item_img"></div>
   <div class="item_txt">Ссылка</div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
   <div class="item_img"></div>
   <div class="item_txt">Ссылка</div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
   <div class="item_img"></div>
   <div class="item_txt">Ссылка</div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
   <div class="item_img"></div>
   <div class="item_txt">Ссылка</div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

ну если не хотите использовать flex, тогда переходите на inine-block

Родителю даёте font-size: 0
дочерним inine-block и размер шрифта

```
.item {
    background: #ccc;
    width: 29.666%;
    margin-right: 5.5%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

ну а вообще лучше flex

```
.wrapper {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Вот тут http://yoksel.github.io/flex-cheatsheet/ - можете поиграться с расстановкой блоков. (если будете использовать justify-content: space-between и убрать margin - то просто сделайте пару лишних блоков пустых item или псевдоэлементы у родителя- потому что  если на последней строке будет останется 2 блока, их раскидает по сторонам )

```css
 @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,400i,500,500i,700,700i');

 body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: #434343;
 }
 .wrapper {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
 }
 .item {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 29.666%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
 }
  .last {
    height: 0;
  }
 
 .item_img {
  height: 190px;
  background: #000;
 }
 .item_txt {
  padding: 10px
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">
   <div class="item_img"></div>
   <div class="item_txt">Какое-то длинное название блока, которое рушит всю можульность остальных блоков</div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
   <div class="item_img"></div>
   <div class="item_txt">Ссылка</div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
   <div class="item_img"></div>
   <div class="item_txt">Ссылка</div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
   <div class="item_img"></div>
   <div class="item_txt">Ссылка</div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
   <div class="item_img"></div>
   <div class="item_txt">Ссылка</div>
  </div>
    <div class="item last"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
 </div>
```

Теперь меняйте размеры (ширину) вам ничего не страшно, равномерные отступы гарантированы...

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!

Answer (score 1):

Решение на `flex`:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 720px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.item {
  flex-basis: 200px;
  margin: 0 20px 15px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.item_img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #000;
}

.item_txt {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item_img"></div>
    <div class="item_txt">Какое-то длинное название блока, которое рушит всю можульность остальных блоков</div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="item_img"></div>
    <div class="item_txt">Ссылка</div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="item_img"></div>
    <div class="item_txt">Ссылка</div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="item_img"></div>
    <div class="item_txt">Ссылка</div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="item_img"></div>
    <div class="item_txt">Ссылка</div>
  </div>
</div>
```